# end Auth Adapter Ldap in 1.10.6 is not backward compatible

Tags: zend-framework, active-directory, ldap, adapter, authentication

Zend Auth Adapter Ldap in 1.10.6 fails when using the same options 
ldap.server1.baseDn = "CN=Users,DC=webex,DC=local"  (this is just one option)
the exact same option works in the previous 1.5 or 1.6 versions

if i change the above option to 
ldap.server1.baseDn = "DC=webex,DC=local"
then it works but would always return Invalid Credentials even if the case is Identity Not Found

does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an option for scope?  Entry, subtree, base perhaps?  Subtree of course is what you want in this context.